# How do you allow html and Javascript files to function in Atom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Code on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMUHw.png)[The button doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFu1S.png)So, I am fairly new to JavaScript and have been looking at tutorials for the language. I downloaded the Atom IDE and began following a video and used the same code as the video to make a web page with a button that reveals a message when clicked. However when I click the button nothing happens, and when I hit inspect element.

It gives me the following error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

It appears as though the HTML file is not working with the .js file. However they are in the same directory.

Here's the updated code (still the same error):

```html
 <DOCTYPE! html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button onclick="revealMessage()">Click me!</button>
        <p id="hiddenMessage" style="display:none">Filosofem</p>
    </body>
    <script>
    function revealMessage() {
      document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202080/discussion-on-question-by-valskarx-how-do-you-allow-html-and-javascript-files-to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, it is the file directory. When you declared `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`, that means that your `script.js` file, must be located in a subfolder called "js".

If you want your  to be within your file, then you can do

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="revealMessage()">Click me!</button>
    <p id="hiddenMessage" style="display:none">Filosofem</p>
</body>
<script>
function revealMessage() {
  document.getElementById("hiddenMessage").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</html>
```

Finally, you should try resaving the code through atom, and make sure your code is the right version of your code.

Comment: I changed the <script> to that but still nothing happens when I click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

By using an external stylesheet you need to make sure your CSS file is saved as said above but with `<script scr="filename.js">/script>` I still haven't found a way other than having your code internal which is completely fine unless you're making a world wide website then it would be easy to hack.